# Calling CPS function from NONCPS function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm pretty new with Jenkins & Groovy and I face with minor issue:
Inside my jenkins pipeline, I have a stage that calls a function that needs to run eachLine command, as you all know to use eachLine command we need to wrap the function with `@NonCPS`.

The issue is that I need to use `sh` command inside the eachLine loop and `sh` command are not allowed inside `@NonCPS` methods.

**For example:**

```
@NonCPS
def SplitGitBlame(String gitBlameOutputAsText)
{
    def gerritUrl = ''
    gitBlameOutputAsText.eachLine{ line ->
        gerritUrl  = sh(returnStdout:true, script: 'gerrit query commit: ${line} --format=text | 
        grep 'url:'')
    }
}
```

(Of course, this is not the full script and there's no logic here, just to demonstrate my problem).

**So my questions are:**

1. There is a way to 'replace' eachLine command with a similar behavior method that not requires @NonCPS wrap?
2. There is a way to execute 'sh' command inside @NonCPS method?

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

can't test it. so, just an idea to go without noncps..

```
def gitBlameOutputAsLines = gitBlameOutputAsText.readLins()
for(line in gitBlameOutputAsLines){
  sh(...)
}
```